# How to get JWT Token through passwordless signin link

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity-toolkit

We (company A) are developing an App. We want to expose functionality of Company B in our App (Post / Get calls to their API).

Requirements:

- Company B wants us to provide a solution that costs them minimal setup time from their end.
- Legally we cannot show a username and password field in our own App to authenticate the user with Company B's API.
- We could ask the e-mail address of the user with a submit button and trigger a password-less flow? But open to better suggestions.

Flow of Company B's App:

- Show login page
- POST call with username and password: `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIz..4E`
- Response call with JWT Token:

  ```
    https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=AI..4E

    Body:
    {
       "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUz...KFQ"
    }
  ```

Pasting this JWT Token in our API calls to Company B is enough for this to work.

Question:

Would a password-less flow work? And if yes, how would I get the JWT Token?

Things tried:

- Tried this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc) but it also refers to a firebase object, and I don't think users are stored on firebase.
- Tried the [firebase email-link signin tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth). They have their userbase on google Identity, and not on Firebase. Otherwise this would be a great implementation.
- [Zapier](https://platform.zapier.com/build/sessionauth) connects to all these thirdparty api's by actually using and storing the user's information. This would be the easiest, but not possible for us.

Comment: I wonder what details the close voters are missing? Maybe they're just unfamiliar with the issue?

Comment: I'm searching for a best practices usecase, maybe this is not common? And upvote then!